# Conexión base de datos INFORMIX a CA ERwin data modeler

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, informix, base-de-datos

Estoy actualmente presentando problemas para establecer la conexión desde el aplicativo de **CA Erwin data modeler** con la base de datos de **INFORMIX IBM**, las ayudas de la aplicación dice que se debe crear el archivo desde el **administrador de OBDC** que tiene windows pero no funciona, no se lista la opción de informix en la aplicación, así como se ve en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como establecer esa conexión a mi BD de INFORMIX desde el aplicativo de modelado de datos CA ERwin

Gracias

Comment: No queda clara la pregunta. Has creado el DSN en el editor de ODBC de Windows?

Comment: Tienes el driver de Informix instalado? este se obtiene instalando el Informix Client SDK que lo puedes descargar desde la web de ibm.

Comment: Gracias, si el DSN lo cree y tiene conexión con la BD al hacer la prueba. lo cree en Admin odbc 32 bit y odbc 64 bits por si acaso, el driver de OBDC para informix está creado si no no me estaría testeando correctamente a la BD